# Nested double quotes in weview.executeScript() & jQuery

Tags: jquery, webview

I need to insert this basic jQuery script :

```
$("[name='password']").value ='p4$$w0RD';
```

Nothing special here, but i want to inject this script in a webview, like this :

```
var wv = document.querySelector('webview');
wv.executeScript({code: "$("[name='password']").value ='p4$$w0RD';"});
```

My problem is there are double quotes inside double quotes, and i can't find a solution..

I'm pretty sure you'll have a solution ! 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know webview, but can't you use an escape character, like \", for these nested double quotes?

Comment: Thank you Arnaud, I already tried to escape, and it still doesn't work